# How to create a Django database backup?

Tags: django

I run multiple (more or less) identical Django (1.11) deployments running on the exact same schema, but different settings (I make my own `Settings` models). Values in these `Settings` models, of which there are plenty, are different for each deployment, so these sites can appear differently depending on the settings, for example.

A business requirement came up that requires me to regularly export these `Settings` models (`DisplaySettings`, `CurrencySettings`, etc.) from one stack, and import them into another stack. I know `dumpdata` and `loaddata` offer basic functionality in the form of JSON files, but I also need these extra functionalities from the business side:

1. The admin must be able to select which settings to export, including `ForeignKey` and `ManyToManyField` relations that may be in these settings.
2. When importing that file, the admin must be able to choose which settings in the file to import, and how (update the existing settings model, or create a new one).
3. The same exported file can be re-imported into the same stack to create duplicate copies of these settings.

Here are the solutions I have tried so far:

1. `dumpdata`/`loaddata`: Does not need the "choose which settings to import/export" requirement.
2. `django-import-export`: only supports exporting of tabular structures, i.e. foreign keys cannot be exported as part of a settings record.
3. `django-easydump`: completely unrelated package that uploads the dump to s3. Can specify which models to include, but not the attributes in each model to include.
4. Writing custom nested `ModelSerializer`s in `djangorestframework`: doable but tedious. Requires custom front-end to handle the first requirement.

My question is: is there already a built-in way to do perform imports/exports as described, or if not, are there any qualifying third-party packages, not listed above, that I have obviously missed?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing built in that will handle all of your requirements.

If the schema is the same across all your deployments the easiest thing to do would be to set up drf endpoints for each model. Unless I'm missing something they don't need to be nested.

```
def import_currency_settings(new=False, remove_fields=[]):
    endpoint = default_domain + '/currency_settings/'
    settings = requests.get(endpoint, auth=(api_user, api_pass)).json()
    for setting in settings:
        for field in remove_fields:
            setting.pop(field, None)
        if new:
            CurrencySettings.objects.create(**setting)
        else:
            updated = setting
            updated.pop('id', None)
            CurrencySettings.update_or_create(
                id=setting['id'],
                fields=updated
            )

import_currency_settings(new=True, remove_fields=['vat'])
```

Comment: This is definitely the basic idea behind my "doable but tedious" DRF implementation, where `CurrencySettings` in your example would have hundreds of FKs and M2Ms in it, which is something DRF can handle. The tedious part is there exists 2000 of these, and I am not yet sure how to tackle the issue with attempting to create objects before their foreign keys (multiple levels, sometimes circular) are also ready.